# Rails primary_key not inherited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema-plus

I have created a SQL view in Rails, using the excellent [Schema Plus Views](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus_views) gem.

In order to DRY up my SQL view models, I have created a superclass for all SQL view models.

```
class SqlView < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.primary_key = :id
  after_initialize :readonly!
end
```

Then I inherit the SQL view

```
class ChallengeView < SqlView

end
```

The problem is self.primary_key is not inherited.

```
irb(main):008:0> c = ChallengeView.find(1)
ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey: Unknown primary key for table challenge_views in model ChallengeView.
```

If I add it to the model it works OK.

```
class ChallengeView < SqlView
  self.primary_key = :id
end


irb(main):001:0> c = ChallengeView.find(1)
  ChallengeView Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "challenge_views".* FROM  "challenge_views" WHERE "challenge_views"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<ChallengeView id: 1, organizer_id: 1, challenge: ....
```

**EDIT**

According to Rails documentation it can be overridden.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 2):

Why not including the configuration as a module?

```
module SqlView
  def included(base)
    base.module_eval do
      self.abstract_class = true
      self.primary_key = :id
      after_initialize :readonly!
    end
  end
end

class ChallengeView < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SqlView
end
```